# JSF / Primefaces dataTable and sorting issue

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 2.2, with JSF 2.0.3.

I have an xhtml view that contains the following datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="fooTable" 
    widgetVar="fooTable" 
    rowKey="#{foo.id}" 
    var="foo" 
    value="#{fooQueue.foos}"
    styleClass="table" 
    selection="#{fooQueue.selectedfoo}" 
    filteredValue="#{fooQueue.filteredfoos}"
    paginatorPosition="bottom" 
    paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" 
    selectionMode="single"
    rowEditListener="#{fooQueue.save}" 
    paginator="true" 
    rows="10" 
    rowIndexVar="#{foo.id}"
    emptyMessage="No foos found with given criteria" 
    rowStyleClass="#{foo.status == const.submitted ? 'gray' : null}"
    onRowSelectUpdate=":form:deleteValidation">

        <p:column id="mothersName" filterBy="#{foo.header1}"  filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Mother's Name" styleClass="tableHeader2" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:commandLink action="#{fooQueue.next(foo)}" 
                ajax="false" 
                disabled="#{foo.status == const.submitted || foo.id == 0}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{foo}" target="#{fooQueue.selectedfoo}" />  
                <h:outputText value="#{foo.header1}" styleClass="tableData" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{foo.header4}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="DOB" styleClass="tableHeader2" style="width: 400px" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{foo.header4}" styleClass="#{(foo.overSevenDays and foo.status != const.submitted and foo.id != 0)?'tableDataRed':'tableData'}" />
        </p:column></p:dataTable>
```

.. with the following backing bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class FooQueue extends BaseViewBean { 

    private List foos;
    private Foo selectedFoo;
    private List filterdFoos;

    public FooQueue() {
        logger.debug("Creating new FooRegQueue");
        retrieveFooRecords();
    }

    private void retrieveFooRecords(){
        foos = new ArrayList();
        foos.addAll(fooService.getAllFoos());
    }

    public String next(Foo clickedFoo) {        
        System.out.println(clickedFoo.getId());     
        return "";
    }

    public Collection getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }

    public Foo getSelectedFoo() {
        return selectedFoo;
    }

    public void setSelectedFoo(Foo foo) {
        if (foo != null) {
            this.selectedFoo = foo;
        }
    }

    public void setFilterdFoos(List filterdFoos) {
        this.filterdFoos = filterdFoos;
    }

    public List getFilterdFoos() {
        return filterdFoos;
    }
}
```

Note the "commandLink" on the mother's name column, and the "sortBy" on the DOB column.

I've encountered a strange issue, which seems to be limited to IE, where if I sort the data by DOB, then paginate to the last page and click the commandLink of the last record in the table, it fires two action events.  The first event correctly reports that I clicked on the last record in the sorted table.  But the second invocation of the next() method is for the last record in the UNsorted table.

Can anyone identify anything wrong with my xhtml, or backing bean?  Is this a known PrimeFaces issue?  A known IE issue?

I am testing with IE 8.

Comment: what pf version are you using?

Comment: I don't think that version of PF is supported anymore. You'll be happier upgrading to the 3.3.X versions. I don't even think cagatay will entertain this :)

Comment: Then I guess my question is were there known issues with version 2.x of primefaces which would have lead to this type of behavior and have those issues been resolves in 3.3.X?  If this same behavior happens in 3.3.X, then what do I do?

Comment: I just noticed that if I select the row first, and then click on the commandLink, it opens the expected record and only fires the action once.  If the row isn't selected and I click on the link, it fires the action twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.  I simply had to change this:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{fooQueue.next(foo)}" 
  ajax="false" 
  disabled="#{foo.status == const.submitted || foo.id == 0}">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{foo}" target="#{fooQueue.selectedfoo}" />  
   <h:outputText value="#{foo.header1}" styleClass="tableData" />
</p:commandLink>
```

to this:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{fooQueue.next(foo)}" 
  ajax="true" 
  disabled="#{foo.status == const.submitted || foo.id == 0}">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{foo}" target="#{fooQueue.selectedfoo}" />  
   <h:outputText value="#{foo.header1}" styleClass="tableData" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Note the **ajax="true"**.  Because it was previously set to ajax="false", it was instantiating a new instance of my backing bean, and the row that was selected in the default sort order was being loaded.  Now it does not instantiate a new instance, and I load the actual record I clicked on.